# How to achieve conditional PAM authentication?

Tags: password, pam

I am currently using

```
auth required pam_unix.so try_first_pass nullok
auth optional pam_ssh.so  use_first_pass
```

(plus some other, probably irrelevant entries Arch Linux added by default), which means my login password is also used to attempt unlocking any ssh-key stored (or linked to) in `~/.ssh/login-keys.d/` thanks to [pam_ssh](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys#pam_ssh) (I could also use `try_first_pass` instead in order to get a passphrase prompt should no ssh key be unlocked by my login password).

This works fine so long as the SSH key passphrase is identical to the login one. However, what I would *like* to achieve is that I can basically login with one of two *different* passwords - either my login one *or* the SSH key one.

So I thought that `pam_ssh` should fist try to unlock my SSH key, and *only if* that fails should `pam_unix` be required, otherwise it should be skipped. Can this be achieved somehow?

---

At first I thought the solution lies in putting `pam_ssh` first, but additionally it has to be made `sufficient` instead of `optional`:

```
auth sufficient pam_ssh.so  try_first_pass
auth required pam_unix.so try_first_pass nullok
```

However, in the real files there are some other `required` lines *following* `required pam_unix.so`, such as `required pam_env.so`, which would now be ignored! So how can I *really* solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to two other SE posts ([one on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28949169/321973), [one on SF](https://serverfault.com/q/644226/45248)), the answer lies in using [advanced `control` syntax](http://linux.die.net/man/5/pam.d). The

```
auth required pam_unix.so try_first_pass nullok
# and sometime later
auth optional pam_ssh.so  use_first_pass
```

should therefore become

```
auth [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=1 ignore=ignore default=ignore] pam_unix.so try_first_pass nullok
auth required pam_ssh.so use_first_pass
```

*Now* it is imperative that the `pam_ssh` line exactly precedes the `pam_unix` one, since `success=N` means to skip `N` following module(s).

Also, don't forget the `session pam_ssh.so` line while you're at it!

---

In my first attempt, I used

```
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_ssh.so try_first_pass
auth required pam_unix.so use_first_pass nullok
```

instead, but this method locks out all users without SSH keys! Turns out that `default=ignore` isn't sufficient, `auth_err=ignore` has to be added since that is apparently *not* considered part of `default`. Also, this attempt means there'll either be a "password" or "SSH passphrase" prompt depending on whether the user *has* an SSH key!

---

Note that in Arch Linux, the `pam_unix` line used by `login` lies in the `include` chain

```
login -> system-local-login -> system-login -> system-auth
```

and that `system-login` has some other `required` *before* including `system-auth`, so you cannot simply put `auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_ssh.so try_first_pass` in before `login`'s `auth include system-local-login` - you'd skip the wrong `required` and thanks to the `pam_unix.so use_first_pass` (instead of `try_first_pass`) you could still only login with your login password! On the other hand, by modifying `system-auth`, you're also allowing *other* services such as `sshd` to use your SSH key as authentication option to the login password. If you truly want only your `login` to use this, you have to pretty much break the `include` chain and manually copy all `auth`s to `login`.

Comment: As a side note, once you logged in using your SSH passphrase, it will also be available to your other sessions'  `ssh-agent`! Fixing this if desired would probably require more effort