# pam options to skip a module FREEBSD

Tags: freebsd, pam

I am looking for something similar to what is posted here:
[How to achieve conditional PAM authentication?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239485/how-to-achieve-conditional-pam-authentication/239486#239486?newreg=cac6f13b5cf44326a106c36a2265ec5b)

But the same does not seem to work on FreeBSD 10. Example [success=1] seems to be not a valid format to be use in pam.d
I was hoping someone could point me to the FreeBSD equivalent of this. Thanks.